# SP2013 Community Site - adding custom content to home page

Tags: 2013, user-controls, community-site

I'm probably missing something basic, but I'm trying to add new user control based content to the `Community Home.aspx` page within a Community Site. How is that done?

I've tried editing the page in my browser, but there's no way to insert web parts (I have a web part wrapper that loads a user control).

I've also tried editing the page directly in Designer, and while I can add the web part while editing the page, when i save the page my added content is removed.

My goal is to add a custom menu to each page within the Community Site, with links to other pages in the site and outside the site. I want them in a menu form at the top of each page.

Any tips would be appreciated.